With .NET 9 escape analysis, are struct and class now equal?
From a memory allocation point of view structs (in most cases) get allocated on the stack and classes get allocated on the heap. Each having their own tradeoffs. And struct vs class is always included in C# job interviews.
Now with .NET 9 escape analysis, if my understating is correct, this concept is no longer true, and classes will be allocated based on JIT judgement. Am I correct?

According to the docs this only applies to unescaped boxes. An optimization, but of little importance tbh.

Not at all. This is an optimization only, and currently very limited. As Stephen Toub explains in Performance Improvements in .NET 9: In .NET 9, object stack allocation starts to happen. Before you get too excited, it’s limited in scope right now, but in the future it’s likely to expand out further.

Even on later versions this won't change the difference between value and reference types. It won't start producing defensive copies or value equality in reference types, nor would it allow allocating a large list or buffer on the stack, or force copying when passing an object to a method

It is technically correct that the .NET 9 JIT decides whether to allocate a class on the stack or the heap, but the cases where it will allocate on the stack are quite limited: The JIT compiler must be able to determine that the allocated class will not be used outside the method where it is allocated.

It also doesn't actually allocate the class on the stack - instead it treats each field in the class as a separate stack variable. And if the class' constructor contains any calls to other methods (eg. Console.WriteLine()) that will also disable the optimisation.

Nothing has changed, nor will it change. This is an optimization, currently limited. As Stephen Toub explains in Performance Improvements in .NET 9:

In .NET 9, object stack allocation starts to happen. Before you get too excited, it’s limited in scope right now, but in the future it’s likely to expand out further.

and

... it’s limited to only handling cases where it can easily prove the object reference doesn’t leave the current frame. Even so, there are plenty of situations where this will help to eliminate allocations, and I expect it’ll be expanded to handle more and more cases in the future. When the JIT does choose to allocate an object on the stack, it effectively promotes the fields of the object to be individual variables in the stack frame.

Even on later versions this won't change the difference between value and reference types. It won't start producing defensive copies or value equality in reference types, nor would it allow allocating a large list or buffer on the stack, or force copying when passing an object to a method.

I wouldn't say "Nothing has changed", clearly some allocation scenarios have changed. But I'm learning here that it's quite limited. Anyway, thank you for your useful information and quotes.

As far as the question is concerned, whether there's still any difference between value and reference types, nothing has changed. JIT optimizations don't change the language itself
